# Add to local repository SVN in Eclipse and error : 'addressing logical'

Tags: eclipse, svn

I create repository by TortoiseSVN and when I want to share project in eclipse
(left click on class -> team ->share project-> I choose SVN -> url: file///my repo ) I have mistakes:

> Share project was failed.
>
> svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>
> svn: E180001: Unable to open repository
>   'file:///C:/SVN/MyNewRepository'
>
> svn: E125006: 'C:\SVN\MyNewRepository\db\format' contains invalid
>   filesystem format option 'addressing logical'

What I should do? Please give me some advice because I can't add anything in my repo

Answer (score 1):

Install a Subversion server and access your repositories over HTTP(S) to solve the problem.

You are getting this error because there is a mix up of Subversion versions in TortoiseSVN and Eclipse. TortoiseSVN 1.9 creates SVN repository in SVN 1.9 format and Eclipse that's using non-standard Subversion client of older version (1.8 or older), does not support accessing this repository directly through `file://` access.