# can't use svn plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm having an awful lot of problems with the Eclipse SVN plugin (subversive).
I have installed it but I don't seem to be able to create a repository. Say I create a new folder C:\new_repo, if I click the new repository location button (the browse button is greyed out) and type file:///C:/new_repo and hit finish I get several errors (even if I use file:///C:\new_repo):

```
svn:E180001:Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn:E180001:Unable to open repository file:///C:\new_repo
svn:E125006:C:\new_repo\db\format contains invalid filesystem format option "addressing logical"
Keep location anyway?
```

I updated - well tried to update - my svn plugin but I got some nice errors towards the end of the installation, here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4iupadWM) of it as it is too long.
So what do you guys suggest, as I'd love to get this to work...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249564/add-to-local-repository-svn-in-eclipse-and-error-addressing-logical

Comment: OK so if I want to add any comment can I do it on the other thread rather than here?